# Replace all words in java

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I'm using the java replaceAll() method for replace matching words in a string. In my case If this word is next to a comma (,) fullstop (.) or anything else like that, this word is not replacing.

example : 
and.
and,
and;
and(

This is the code:

```
body = body.replaceAll("(?i) "+knownWord + " ", replaceWord);
```

Can anyone please suggest me an regular expression which is capable of identifying all the words in this string?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match **specific knownWord** do:

```
  body = body.replaceAll("(?i)\\b"+knownWord + "\\b", replaceWord);
```

I think what you were looking for is the `\\b` (word boundary) it is used to detect where words start/end, so commas or dots should no longer be a problem then.

More **detailed example** in response to your comment:

```
 String body = "I'm going to school. ";
 String knownWord = "school";
 String replaceWord = "shop";
 System.out.println(body.replaceAll("(?i)\\b"+knownWord + "\\b", replaceWord));
```

The above will print out the following:

> I'm going to shop.

Comment: Thank you for this solution I'm trying this now and I'll get back to you with results.

Comment: @Asanka sure ;-) let me know if it worked at the end or if you need more help.

Comment: This does not prevent words next to punctuation from being detected, as is specified by the OP.

Comment: @aliteralmind I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: Oh, so he *can't figure out* how to replace words next to punctuation, is that it? I thought "If this word is next to a comma (,) fullstop (.) or anything else like that, this word is not replacing." meant "should not be replaced." Jeepers. Oh well...

Comment: @donfuxx I tested your code. But still it is not replacing words.

I'll explain my problem again.


sentence: I'm going to school. 

So I need to replace 'school' with 'shop'

Comment: @Asanka have you set `knownWord = "school";` and `replaceWord = "shop";` before?

Comment: Yes That was my fault your code is working... Thank you very much for helping me...

Comment: @Asanka no problem. Regex are a bit confusing at the beginning, but once you know how to use them well you cannot live without them anymore ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This does as you specify:

```
(?<![.,])\b(\w+)\b(?![.,])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BB98IBBCFRPmkGCH)

It finds (and captures) words as long as they are not next to commas or periods. Just add whatever punctuation marks you like to the character-classes, such as `[.,?(]`.

Here is the regex escaped for a Java string: `"(?<![.,])\\b(\\w+)\\b(?![.,])"`

As far as ignoring case, just pass the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag to your Pattern object, such as with

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(theAbovePattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: + 1 for illustrative explanation, but I think @Asanka actually wants to replace words also if they are next to `.,`

Comment: Yeah. I thought he meant opposite: That he couldn't *figure out how* to capture words next to punctuation  :)

Comment: @aliteralmind Could you please replace this code with that regular expression you wrote.

body = body.replaceAll("(?i) "+knownWord + " ", replaceWord); Because I'm ignoring the case sensitivity as well.